# onsubmit breaks Jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a form page that takes some inputs, stores the data in mongo and returns the data to the view underneath the form. However, when a user submits new data on the form, the jade view crashes and displays the following error:

```
TypeError: /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/food/views/index.jade:29
    27|         label
    28|           input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;")
  > 29|       each Entry, i in entries
    30|         div.title= Entry.title
    31|         div.url= Entry.url
    32|         div.selectedDate= Entry.selectedDate

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The expected behaviour is that when a user submits new data through the form, it displays underneath the form. Why does `Entry` become undefined onsubmit but the data still displays prior to a submit?

Router

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  Entry.find({}, function (err, entries) {
    res.render('index', {
      "entries": entries
    });
  });
});
```

Jade

```
block content
  .container
    h1 London Plans
    form(method='post' action='post', class='plans', id='plans')
      .form-group
        label Do you have a link?
        input.form-control(name='search', id='search' type='url', required='required')
        h2#title
      .form-group
        label What looks cool?
        input.form-control(name='title', type='text', required='required' class='title')
      .form-group
        label When is it?
        label
          input(type='checkbox' name='week' value='week')
          span This week
        label
          input(type='checkbox' name='month' value='month')
          span This Month
        label
          input(type='checkbox' id='date')
          span Date
        label
          input(type='textbox' class='datepicker' name='date' value='')
        label
          input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;")
      each Entry, i in entries
        div.title= Entry.title
        div.url= Entry.url
        div.selectedDate= Entry.selectedDate
```

Post function

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res, next) {
  var url = req.body.search;
  var title = req.body.title;
  var week = req.body.week;
  var month = req.body.month;
  var date = req.body.date;

  console.log(url + ' ' + title + ' ' + week + ' ' + month + ' ' + date);

  //FIND WHICH DATE WAS SELECTED BY USER AND ASSIGN THAT TO selectedDate
  if (typeof week != 'undefined' ){
    var selectedDate = 'week';
  } else if (typeof month != 'undefined') {
    var selectedDate = 'month';
  } else {
    var selectedDate = date;
  };

  //CREATE NEW OBJECT
  var data = new Entry ({
    url: url,
    title: title,
    selectedDate: selectedDate
  })

  //STORE NEW OBJECT TO THE DB
  Entry.createEntry(data, function(err, entry){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(entry);
  })

  //RENDER THE HOMEPAGE TO CLEAR THE FORM
  res.render('index');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Because you're rendering the page without entries in the second last line of code. Try it like `res.render('index', {entries: []});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why entries is undefined upon resubmission is because in your `router.post` handler you're not supplying the Jade template with a value for that variable.

Here is the code in your `router.post` handler which causes this:

```
res.render('index'); // telling the page to render without variables
```

Now, compare this to the successful code in the `router.get` handler:

```
res.render('index', {
    "entries": entries // here is where you assign variables for Jade
});
```

As you can see, in the `router.get` handler you're supplying the Jade template engine with a value for the `"entries"` variable with `entries`, which is a value returned by the call you make to mongodb.

It might be worth having a look at [the express docs for `res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) for more information. Here's the excerpt in question which sheds some light on the situtation:

> ## `res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])`
>
> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.
>   Optional parameters:
>
> **`locals`, an object whose properties define local variables for the
>   view.**

From the definition of the `locals` argument, you can see where you went wrong! Happy coding :)